# MigLayout 50% width

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I have a Panel which is a contentPane of a `JDialog`. That Panel is divided horizontally into two parts. `UpperHalfPanel` and `LowerHalfPanel` by:

```
Panel.add("UpperHalfPanel", "wrap");
Panel.add("LowerHalfPanel");
```

The `LowerHalfPanel` is divided vertically into two parts. `LowerHalfLeftPanel` and `LowerHalfRightPanel`.

Now the size of the `UpperHalfPanel` is determined by number of columns of a `JTextField` and I am finding a way to make the `LowerHalfLeftPanel` and `LowerHalfRightPanel` fill 50% of width of `LowerHalfPanel`.

Briefly it can be described as a Table with two row and the bottom row has two equal column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for split/span.  Without more of a code example, it's hard to say.  A lot of times I find that MigLayout makes nested panels unnecessary.  If you come up with a simple short example or even a mock image, it would help.

It sounds like you want this:

```
JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
JPanel upperPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel lowerLeftPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel lowerRightPanel = new JPanel();

outerPanel.add(upperPanel, "span 2, wrap");
outerPanel.add(lowerLeftPanel);
outerPanel.add(lowerRightPanel);
```

This will make upper panel span 2 "cells" and the lower left and right be evenly divided under it depending on the contents of those panels.  There are ways to force the size, such as the "!" or "wmin".  Try out the [swing demo](http://www.miglayout.com/), go to the span section.  Right clicking on the areas will let you experiment with the contraints.  Also see the MigLayout [cheat sheet](http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/mavensite/docs/cheatsheet.pdf).

Comment: Is there a span for vertical cells?

Comment: @Kieveli: You can add 'flowy' or 'flowx' to indicate on a component that the next component will be placed vertically or horizontally. It defaults to flowx.  I like your style btw.

Comment: I think that would be `spany`.  But I'm getting rusty at Miglayout now.  Too much web development pushing it out of my brain, and I have (thankfully) left Swing behind.